# Use uniform boundedness principle

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ and $Y$ be normed spaces and E be a bounded, complete convex subset of $X$. A map $F$ from $E$ to $Y$ is called affine if $F(tx+(1-t)y)=tF(x)+(1-t)F(y)$ for all $0<t<1$ and $x,y$ are elements of $E$. Let $F^*$ be a set of continuous affine maps from $E$ to $Y$. I want to show that either the set $\{\|F(x)\| :F \in F^*\}$ is unbounded for each $x$ in some dense subset of $E$, or else $F^*$ is uniformly bounded on $E$.

We have to use uniform boundedness principle.

**Attempt:** Assume that the set $\{\|F(x)\| : F \in F^*\}$ is bounded for some $x$, then we need to prove that $F^*$ is uniformly bounded on $E$.
 The uniform boundedness principle says that $F^*$ be a subset of  $BL(X,Y)$  such that for each $x$ in $X$, the set $\{F(x) : F \in F^*\}$ is bounded in $Y$. Then $F^*$ is uniformly bounded on $E$. But we have it for some $x$, how to go further?

Comment: I've made the minimal edits required to make this readable. In future,  pleasre try to format using [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). You might want to look over it and make further changes (for example I think you switch between $X$ and $E$ at various points).

Comment: Thank you, i don't have math jax. Is it available for Android too

Comment: Mathkax is built into the site so you dont need to have it! Just follow the guidelines in the page I linked to and math.se will automatically render it for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly use UBP, but can imitate the proof.

Suppose $\{\Vert F(x)\Vert :F\in F^*\}$ is bounded in a small closed ball $B\subset E$, which is also complete, convex and bounded, thus is a Baire space.

Let $G_n=\{x:\sup_{F\in F^*}\Vert F(x)\Vert\leq n\}$. So $B=\bigcup_n G_n$. Due to BCT, $\exists\ n_0\in\mathbb{N}_+$ s.t. $G_{n_0}$ is dense in a smaller ball $B(x_0,\delta)\subset B\subset E$. By continuity of $F$s, 
$$\sup_{x\in B(x_0,\delta)}\{\Vert F(x)\Vert :F\in F^*\}\leq n_0.$$

Since $E$ is bounded, there exists a real number $M$ s.t. $E\subset B(x_0,M)$.

$\forall x\in E$, $\frac{\delta(x-x_0)}{2\Vert x-x_0\Vert}+x_0\in B(x_0,\delta)$  (convexity of $E$). Therefore,

\begin{eqnarray}
\Vert F(x)\Vert &=& \frac{2\Vert x-x_0\Vert}{\delta}\Vert F \left(\frac{\delta(x-x_0)}{2\Vert x-x_0\Vert}+x_0\right)-\frac{2\Vert x-x_0\Vert-\delta}{2\Vert x-x_0\Vert}F(x_0)\Vert\\
&\leq& 2M\delta^{-1}n_0+(2M\delta^{-1}+1)\Vert F(x_0)\Vert<+\infty.
\end{eqnarray}